# UNION multi select statement with defferent number of columns

Tags: mysql, select, union, union-all

how can i union these select statements that each table has different number of columns?

```
(SELECT title, description, full_description, keywords, option1, option2, option3, option4, option5, option6, option7, option8 FROM articles WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR full_description LIKE ? OR keywords LIKE ? OR option1 LIKE ? OR option2 LIKE ? OR option3 LIKE ? OR option4 LIKE ? OR option5 LIKE ? OR option6 LIKE ? OR option7 LIKE ? OR option8 LIKE ?) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT title, description, full_description, keywords, option1, option2, option3, option4, option5, option6, option7, option8 FROM news WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR full_description LIKE ? OR keywords LIKE ? OR option1 LIKE ? OR option2 LIKE ? OR option3 LIKE ? OR option4 LIKE ? OR option5 LIKE ? OR option6 LIKE ? OR option7 LIKE ? OR option8 LIKE ?) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT title, description, full_description, keywords, option1, option2, option3, option4, option5, option6, option7, option8 FROM products WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR full_description LIKE ? OR keywords LIKE ? OR option1 LIKE ? OR option2 LIKE ? OR option3 LIKE ? OR option4 LIKE ? OR option5 LIKE ? OR option6 LIKE ? OR option7 LIKE ? OR option8 LIKE ?) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT title, description, option1, option2, option3, option4, option5, option6, option7, option8 FROM gallery_images WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR option1 LIKE ? OR option2 LIKE ? OR option3 LIKE ? OR option4 LIKE ? OR option5 LIKE ? OR option6 LIKE ? OR option7 LIKE ? OR option8 LIKE ?) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT title, description, option1, option2, option3, option4, option5, option6, option7, option8 FROM pages WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR option1 LIKE ? OR option2 LIKE ? OR option3 LIKE ? OR option4 LIKE ? OR option5 LIKE ? OR option6 LIKE ? OR option7 LIKE ? OR option8 LIKE ?)
```

i recieve this error :

```
The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply: you can't - you must add some blank columns (e.g. `NULL as blank1`) to those subqueries which have less than maximum # of columns

Answer (score 1):

Simply use NULL value as placeholder for missing fields.

This should work:

```
(SELECT title, description, full_description, keywords, option1, option2, option3, option4, option5, option6, option7, option8 FROM articles WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR full_description LIKE ? OR keywords LIKE ? OR option1 LIKE ? OR option2 LIKE ? OR option3 LIKE ? OR option4 LIKE ? OR option5 LIKE ? OR option6 LIKE ? OR option7 LIKE ? OR option8 LIKE ?) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT title, description, full_description, keywords, option1, option2, option3, option4, option5, option6, option7, option8 FROM news WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR full_description LIKE ? OR keywords LIKE ? OR option1 LIKE ? OR option2 LIKE ? OR option3 LIKE ? OR option4 LIKE ? OR option5 LIKE ? OR option6 LIKE ? OR option7 LIKE ? OR option8 LIKE ?) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT title, description, full_description, keywords, option1, option2, option3, option4, option5, option6, option7, option8 FROM products WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR full_description LIKE ? OR keywords LIKE ? OR option1 LIKE ? OR option2 LIKE ? OR option3 LIKE ? OR option4 LIKE ? OR option5 LIKE ? OR option6 LIKE ? OR option7 LIKE ? OR option8 LIKE ?) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT title, description, NULL AS full_description, NULL AS keywords, option1, option2, option3, option4, option5, option6, option7, option8 FROM gallery_images WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR option1 LIKE ? OR option2 LIKE ? OR option3 LIKE ? OR option4 LIKE ? OR option5 LIKE ? OR option6 LIKE ? OR option7 LIKE ? OR option8 LIKE ?) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT title, description, NULL AS full_description, NULL AS keywords, option1, option2, option3, option4, option5, option6, option7, option8 FROM pages WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR option1 LIKE ? OR option2 LIKE ? OR option3 LIKE ? OR option4 LIKE ? OR option5 LIKE ? OR option6 LIKE ? OR option7 LIKE ? OR option8 LIKE ?)
```